# Is this problem a classification or regression?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, classification

In a lecture from Andrew Ng, he asked whether the problem below is a classification or a regression problem. Answer: It is a regression problem.

> You have a large inventory of identical items. You want to predict how
>   many of these items will sell over the next 3 months.

Looks like I am missing something. Per my understanding it should be classification problem. Reason is we have to classify each item in two categories i.e it can be sold or not, which are discrete value not the continuous ones.

Not sure where is the gap in my understanding.

Comment: In the problem statement, "how many of these items" implies the outcome should be a real value [0, inf]. So, it's a regression problem rather than classification.

Comment: @twcmchang Does it mean If I ask for individual item can be sold or not, it will be classification problem then ?

Comment: `how many` implies determining an amount, which means it is a regression problem. A classification problem would state something like `whether or not` or something like `what type of`.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 You said `how many implies determining an amount, which means it is a classification problem` I hope you meant its not classification problem ?

Comment: @user3198603: Fixed it. Should have been "a regression problem."

Comment: If the original question had been a classification problem, it would have been stated like: `You have a large inventory of books. You want to predict which ones will become best sellers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is that you have a database of items with their respective features and want to predict if each item will be sold. At the end, you would simply count the number of items that can be sold. If you frame the problem this way, then it would be a classification problem indeed.

However, note the following sentence in your question:

> You have a large inventory of identical items.

**Identical items** means that all items will have exactly the same features. If you come up with a binary classifier that tells whether a product can be sold or not, since all feature values are exactly the same, your classifier would put all items in the same category.

I would guess that, to solve this problem, you would probably have access to the time-series of sold items per month for the past 5 years, for instance. Then, you would have to crunch this data and interpolate to the future. You won't be classifying each item individually but actually calculating a numerical value that indicates the number of sold items for 1, 2, and 3 months in the future.

According to [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning (Christopher M. Bishop, 2006)](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387310732):

> Cases such as the digit recognition example, in which the aim is to assign each input vector to one of a finite number of discrete categories, are called *classification* problems. If the desired output consists of one or more continuous variables, then the task is called *regression*.

On top of that, it is important to understand the difference between [categorical, ordinal, and numerical variables](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/what-is-the-difference-between-categorical-ordinal-and-numerical-variables/), as defined in statistics:

> A categorical variable (sometimes called a nominal variable) is one that has two or more categories, but there is no intrinsic ordering to the categories.  For example, gender is a categorical variable having two categories (male and female) and there is no intrinsic ordering to the categories.
>
> (...)
>
> An ordinal variable is similar to a categorical variable.  The difference between the two is that there is a clear ordering of the variables.  For example, suppose you have a variable, economic status, with three categories (low, medium and high).  In addition to being able to classify people into these three categories, you can order the categories as low, medium and high.
>
> (...)
>
> An numerical variable is similar to an ordinal variable, except that the intervals between the values of the numerical variable are equally spaced.  For example, suppose you have a variable such as annual income that is measured in dollars, and we have three people who make $10,000, $15,000 and $20,000.

Although your end result will be an integer (a discrete set of numbers), note it is still a [numerical value, not a category](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/what-is-the-difference-between-categorical-ordinal-and-numerical-variables/). You can manipulate mathematically numerical values (e.g. calculate the average number of sold items in the next year, find the peak number of sold items in the next 3 months...) but you cannot do that with discrete categories (e.g. what would be the average of a cellphone and a telephone?).

Classification problems are the ones where the output is either categorical or ordinal (discrete categories, as per Bishop). Regression problems output numerical values (continuous variables, as per Bishop).

Your system might be restricted to outputting integers, instead of real numbers, but won't change the nature of the variable from being numerical. Therefore, your problem is a regression problem.

Comment: Thanks Matheus. But If I go by the Christopher definition of regression you qouted, here output will be discrete value i.e how many items can be sold for each month over next 3 months ?

Comment: @user3198603 The main point is that classifiers predict discrete *categories*, not numerical values. I updated my answer with a link explaining in more details the difference between categorical, ordinal, and numerical values, a concept from statistics that is crucial to understand the difference between classification and regression.

Comment: Yeah You are right got it. Actually for better understanding we can say classifier predicts the discrete value (or classes) from predefined  classes but for regression outcome can be any continuous value which can not be predefined.

Comment: One related question to `you would probably have access to the time-series of sold items ...` My question is it feasible to tell regression model to pick the specific features(like sales month, festival, economic slowdown) of month to make prediction . I believe we can specify the features but if we don't specify it will pick them automatically whatever it thinks are relevant. Is that correct ?